# What ETFs and mutual funds track the Carhart 4 factors best? I.e. how to replicate these factors cheaply?

Tags: regression, fama-french, etf, mutual-fund

I am looking for a portfolio of ETFs and mutual funds that tracks market, size, value and momentum factors.

One ETF/mutual fund per factor. So say that I want an ETF that tracks the value factor (let's call the return on that ETF $r^{value}_t$), what I am looking for is for an asset whose regression:

$r^{value}  = \alpha_{value} + \beta^{value} HML^{Cahart} + \epsilon_t^{value}$

It should have a high $R^2$ and a $\beta^{value}$ close to 1.

Any suggestions of such ETFs/mutual funds?

Comment: Do you want the ``academic'' factor to be replicated? As I understand it, even DFA and AQR who are quite involved in the academic research don't follow the strict academic conventions but use different rebalancing schemes, weighting schemes, etc to optimise on trading costs. I think most would also use a composite of different value variables (price to sales, earnings, dividends, cashflow, book), remove industry bets, etc. etc… But you don't look for a practitioner-optimised factor, nor standard (long-only) ETFs but one that most closely mimics the returns on Ken French's website?

Comment: I understand that the academic factor is almost impossible to replicate. I want a single ETF/Mutual Fund (either long-only or short-long) that closest tracks those factors.

Comment: There was an article a year ago by Nicholas Apergis: How well do factor ETFs capture the Fama-French factors? in JOIM. Unfortunately it is restricted access, I don't know of a freely available copy.

Comment: Thanks @nbbo2. I have access to that article. Still not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Think one of the issues you'll have is that a lot of these ETF's will have very limited history (as they might have only been created in the last 5-7 years). For example, I checked how well a list of ~60 ETFs tracked a momentum index (similar to the CH4 definition) and the one with the highest correlation was `GMOM` which however only has a history of 7 years.